# How to create new column in first pandas dataframe using index of second pandas dataframe based on certain conditions in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let me describe the problem using simple example.

Lets say we have df1 and df1 created as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 4, 7, 10],
               'year': [2012, 2014, 2013, 2014],
               'sale': [55, 40, 84, 31]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'month1': [2,3,4,1, 4, 7, 10],
                   'year1': [2012,2012,2012,2012, 2014, 2013, 2014],
                   'sale1': [34,35,36,55, 40, 84, 31]})
df2.set_index(pd.Index([100, 200, 300, 411,444,415,416]))
```

now df1 and df2 looks like

```
   month    year    sale
0   1   2012    55
1   4   2014    40
2   7   2013    84
3   10  2014    31

    month1  year1   sale1
100 2   2012    34
200 3   2012    35
300 4   2012    36
411 1   2012    55
444 4   2014    40
415 7   2013    84
416 10  2014    31
```

Now for each row of df1, we find the index of df2 such that df1.month=df2.month1, df1.year=df2.year1, df1.sale=df2.sale1. For the first row of df1, we find index in df2 which is 411. We do this for all values in df1 and create a new column in df1 which stores this index

the final df1 would look like:

```
  month year    sale    index_result
0   1   2012    55  411
1   4   2014    40  444
2   7   2013    84  415
3   10  2014    31  416
```

Here,

1. we cannot guarantee that only one unique index of df2 matched with the condition. In that case, we take the first value only.
2. column names between two dataframes would be different(i have just used suffix 1 here). This need not be too much of a concern as I can create temporary dataframes with new column names so that column names matches. But both dataframes have multiple other columns having different names.

Since I come from c++ background, I can implement a loop solution but it would be very inefficient as df1 in my case has thousands of rows and df2 has millions of rows.

I am looking for an efficient solution in terms of time.. I think I have enough ram on my system, so memory should not be an issue.

If asking for full solution is too much, I would appreciate any leads which can lead me to an efficient solution.

I could not find any similar query in stackoverflow. If somebody can point to a duplicate query, that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to go the [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) route:

```
import pandas as pd

# I have added an additional duplicate row to df2 illustrate your first point
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 4, 7, 10],
               'year': [2012, 2014, 2013, 2014],
               'sale': [55, 40, 84, 31]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'month1': [2,3,4,1, 4, 7, 10, 1],
                   'year1': [2012,2012,2012,2012, 2014, 2013, 2014, 2012],
                   'sale1': [34,35,36,55, 40, 84, 31, 0]})
df2 = df2.set_index(pd.Index([100, 200, 300, 411,444,415,416, 500]))

df1 = (
    pd.merge(
        df1,
        df2.drop_duplicates(subset=["month1", "year1"]).reset_index(names="index_result"),
        left_on=["month", "year"],
        right_on=["month1", "year1"],
        how="left"
    )
    [["month", "year", "sale", "index_result"]]
)
```

out:

```
   month  year  sale  index_result
0      1  2012    55           411
1      4  2014    40           444
2      7  2013    84           415
3     10  2014    31           416
```

but note that the labels you're looking for being part of the index in df2 is a bit awkward here. I simply reset them back into df2, then select them at the end.

Comment: drop duplicate before merge is better.

Comment: Thank you Chrysophylaxs for your help. The solution provided by you takes 7 seconds for my use case. The solution provided by Serge takes 33 seconds. I have marked your solution as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
df1['index_result'] = [df2.query('month1 == {} and year1 == {} and sale1 == {}'.format(row['month'], row['year'], row['sale'])).index[0] for _, row in df1.iterrows()]
```

which gives you

```
 month year    sale    index_result
0   1   2012    55  411
1   4   2014    40  444
2   7   2013    84  415
3   10  2014    31  416
```

Comment: Thank you Serge for your help. The solution provided by you takes 33 seconds for my use case. The solution provided by Chrysophylaxs takes 7 seconds. I have marked solution by Chrysophylaxs as the accepted answer.